# How do I get the AD Display Name of the currently logged in user

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, active-directory

Consider the following properties as set up in Active Directory for a user:

[image]

In my winforms application I would like to show the **Display Name** of the user who is currently logged on and using the application.  How would I go about retrieving this information?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since you're on .NET 4, you can use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find currently logged in user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

string displayName = user.DisplayName;
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD.

Comment: Why did you grab ctx and not use it?  (i'm having issues with AD and stumbled across this answer)

Comment: I would like to know why you dont use ctx aswell

Comment: @Jannik: this is code from a bigger example where I do use the `ctx` - it's not really necessary here for this single statement

Comment: Thaniks man, its been a long time since you wrote this, appreaciate your comment

Comment: `The LDAP server is unavailable.`

Answer (score 12):

After hours of searching for the simplest way I finally came across this

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;
```

I wanted to get it out there for more people like me.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, for a powershell script. Excellent.

Comment: Worked great. The only thing I cant get from this is the users manager?

Comment: When I do this I get "cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal" error...