# Get Windows User Display Name

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

How do I get the *display name* of the user that is logged in? Not the *username*, but the *display name*, such as is shown in the screenshot below - and as seen on the start menu in any Windows Vista/7 computer.

[image]

I tried a bunch of different suggestions from other questions, but they all show the *username*, not the *display name*. You can see the results of these attempts in the above screenshot.

```
Imports System.Security.Principal
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO
Imports System

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MsgBox("1: " & System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString & vbCrLf & _
               "2: " & Environment.UserDomainName & vbCrLf & _
               "3: " & WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name & vbCrLf & _
                "4: " & Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name & vbCrLf & _
               "5: " & Environment.UserName & vbCrLf & _
               "6: " & My.User.Name & vbCrLf &
                "7: " & My.Computer.Name)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Environment.UserName works fine here.

Comment: no. the answer there is not what I wanted.

Comment: In what context is the code using `Environment.UserName` running? Is it in ASP.Net, windows service, normal desktop app, etc ...

Comment: it is running in windows forms

Comment: are you sure you didnt "try" `My.Cmputer.Name` because `Environment.UserName` is the well, user name

Comment: @Codemunkeee u can refer the first link... where u can find the answer

Comment: @Codemunkeee Why is the answer there "not what you wanted"? Does it produce incorrect output?

Comment: Plutonix yes I did, all the links say the same functions and calls.. killer R what link are you referring to?
Asad I have edited my question.. you can see from the output..

Comment: Of course you had to hide the only important bit of code under the dialog.

Comment: If you application is running under another user, you will get that other user name.

Comment: I will post all the codes that I used. As of now I'm still listing them

Comment: I don't really understand why it's marked as duplicate.

Comment: because the other question answer your question. Also, read the comments.

Comment: No, the other question did not answer my question. I'll read the comments now.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate and should be reopened. It wasn't clear what the OP was asking, but the question is NOT about the username, its about the display name shown in the screenshot.

Comment: The correct answer is 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName' (and add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll') which is not mentioned in any of the answers on the question of which this one is supposedly a duplicate.

Comment: @Tim - if you figured what OP wants you should edit question itself as OP does not see need to do so (or don't see why other readers get the question differently)... You probably right that image showing random code actually does not show code but start menu...

Comment: Then let's reopen the question

Comment: I edited the question for the OP. Is that better?

Comment: @Pierre-AlainVigeant re-open question looks missed out few comments ! (btw good to know you can make dead alive (re open) on stack overflow )

Comment: answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438634/how-to-get-logged-in-users-full-name-in-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the AD Display Name of the currently logged in user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692767/how-do-i-get-the-ad-display-name-of-the-currently-logged-in-user)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should use [`UserPrincipal.DisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.displayname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_Principal_DisplayName):

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName
```

To do so, you'll need to and add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` from your project.

Note: Doesn't work when machine is unplugged from the network or domain server is not reachable.

Comment: I used this approach, but in the real world I'm seeing the getter for UserPrincipal.Current throwing a PrincipalServerDownException. I believe the case is when the current user is logged in with a domain account, but the directory server can't be contacted, such as when a laptop has been unplugged from the network. Use this method with caution, it doesn't seem to be reliable!

Comment: Roger Sanders is right, use this variable with caution. In my case there was a long delay on the network so this method hangs for a while.

Comment: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.
`

Answer (score -3):

Try this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0(v=vs.110).aspx

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Codemunkeee When describing a problem, saying "it's not working" is useless. In order to receive help you have to tell us what is going wrong. Do you see an exception? If so, what is the exception? Is the result unexpected? How so?

Comment: You can refer to my question above. As you can see it returns a different output, I'll edit the code again to list all the things that I did..

Comment: @Codemunkeee can you please try the above code and paste what console output you are getting

Comment: still the same bro :(

Comment: okay.. wait.. I'm still editing the code and all the things that I've used

Comment: I have edited my question, there you can see all the things that I did.

Answer (score -4):

This is contained within the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace so you need to add this in the `using` section.

Then you can use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName` which returns the `Display Name`. This is typically shown in the Start Menu.