# How to get the current Windows User Account Name efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, user-accounts

I am trying to get "*current active user account name*" (Windows user).

For that I have tried the below mentioned code and I get the "*current active user account name*", but this code first get all users list and then filters (get) the "*current active user name*".

Now, I am trying to get "*current active user account name*" (Windows user) but without a `for` loop and I tried to get help (research) in Microsoft Developer Documentation but I could not able to find helpful resources.

```
SelectQuery userListQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount");
ManagementObjectSearcher userSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(userListQuery);

foreach (ManagementObject envVar in userSearcher.Get())
{
    // get sid string from username (for to acsess user's current_user registry key)
    NTAccount userAccount = new NTAccount(envVar["Name"].ToString());
    SecurityIdentifier sid = (SecurityIdentifier)userAccount.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
    string sidString = sid.ToString();

    File.AppendAllText("c:\\outs\\log.txt", " ---- user account  ----" + userAccount + "\n\n");
    File.AppendAllText("c:\\outs\\log.txt", " ---- sid string  ----" + sidString + "\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the current username in .NET using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c) and [Get Windows User Display Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187761/get-windows-user-display-name) and [How do I get the currently-logged username from a Windows service in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218778/how-do-i-get-the-currently-logged-username-from-a-windows-service-in-net)

Comment: those answers gives me username but I want to get "current user account name"

Comment: @.SARKAR Isn't that thing there? https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity

Comment: From what context are you looking? Is the code you are executing running with a user's token (for example, did a user double click an icon or type the command name in a CMD window)?

Comment: @Flydog57 this code is in script(with user token). my aim is to get "sid" string and edit registry on specific actions by user in the windows application.

Comment: Don't know what "in script" means, but why wouldn't you use `var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();` and then look at the details of that user (particularly; `var sid = user.User?.Value;`)

Comment: And, are you using this to look the current user up by SID in HKEY_ALL_USERS?  Why not just use HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: I need the current windows user account name(system) but `var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();` returns current active username.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem using:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
var collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```