# How to get underline object?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am getting a ADGroup using this code,

```
        using (var context = Utilities.GetPrincipalContext(OU))
        using (var gpe = new GroupPrincipalExtension(context, "*"))
        using (var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(gpe))
        {
            foreach (var g in ps.FindAll())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(g.DisplayName);
            }
        }
```

It's giving DisplayName null, because the attribute is available but under another object, here is what I see in LOCAL window when debugging,

[image]

**Edit**

I thought code was self explaining but if it causes confusion, I am trying to get all groups in a specific OU, then trying to get a custom attribute "DisplayName", GroupPrincipalExtension inherits from GroupPrincipal class of system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.

When debugging I can see "g" object has Test.AD.GroupPrincipalExtension  (I don't know what to call it ? underline object ? a property ? not sure...) which has DisplayName property.

Because I can't get `g.DisplayName`, how can i get following,

```
g.Test.AD.GroupPrincipalExtension.DisplayName
```

Comment: I didn't vote yet, but its really not clear what you are asking. What are you trying to do? Have you seen this question? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692767/how-do-i-get-the-ad-display-name-of-the-currently-logged-in-user) does that help you?

Comment: @RoyT. I updated my question to make it more obvious to get an answer

Comment: You should really show your objects structure.

Comment: @Kamo I am inheriting from this class - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no path `g.Test.AD.GroupPrincipalExtension.DisplayName`. Visual Studio just shows you that `g` is of type `Test.AD.GroupPrincipalExtension` (since `g` is of type `Principal`).

Since you use `gpe` as a filter on `PrincipalSearcher`, the type you see is `GroupPrincipalExtension`. (Your `GroupPrincipalExtension` inherits `Principal`, which is the type `PrincipalSearchResult<Principal>` enumerates over, as you do in your `foreach`).

You have to find for the issue somewhere else, maybe in your `GroupPrincipalExtension`. The call to [`Principal.DisplayName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.displayname(v=vs.110).aspx) is okay.